# Spring Boot POST endpoint returning 405 instead of 200

Tags: java, http, cucumber, bdd, acceptance-testing

I am running the following Cucumber step definition:

```
Given("we have set the following data:", (final DataTable dataTable) -> {
            final var map = dataTable.asLists(String.class).stream().skip(1)
                    .collect(toMap(row -> row.get(0), row -> row.get(1)));

            final var bodyPublisher = HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(
                    new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(map));

            final var request = newBuilder(
                    create("http://localhost:" + applicationPort + ORGANIZATION_ENDPOINT))
                    .header("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                    .header("Authorization", BASIC_AUTHORIZATION_USER_PASSWORD_BASE64)
                    .POST(bodyPublisher).build();

            assertThat(newHttpClient().send(request, ofString()).statusCode(), is(200));
        });
```

That is hitting the following endpoint:

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/api/v1/endpoint", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Map<String, Map> setData(@RequestBody final Map<String, String> map) {
        validateInputMap(map);
        log.info(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "-> setData: " + map);
        service.addData(map);
        return service.retrieve(data);
    }
```

However it is returning a *405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED* instead of *200*, so it  is hitting the endpoint but for some reason not as a *POST*.

Any hint?

Thank you!

EDIT:

The body publisher body is:

```
{
"Jane Morgan":"John Smith",
"John Smith":"Jack Diaz",
"Jack Diaz":"Sarah Logan",
"Jacob Hare":"John Smith"
}
```

Comment: In most cases, this status indicates an invalid request body format. Can you show what your `bodyPublisher` looks like?

Comment: Thanks @M.Dudek, updated question. It is just receiving a map like this one exactly:{
"Jane Morgan":"John Smith",
"John Smith":"Jack Diaz",
"Jack Diaz":"Sarah Logan",
"Jacob Hare":"John Smith"
}